# Type Miss-Match Java

Tags: java

I have a separate class called DictEntry. In my own class Dictionary, I have

```
private LinkedList<DictEntry> dictList = new LinkedList<DictEntry>(); //initiate linked list
private int sizeOfArray; //variable for size of Array [must be prime number]
private DictEntry table[] = new DictEntry[sizeOfArray]; // array of type DictEntry
table[keyCode]= dictList.add(pair); //[ERROR] Type MissMatch, Cannot Convert boolean to type DictEntry
```

I've already declared the array and linked list as type DictEntry, why is it still asking for boolean?

When I declare LinkedList as String and use .add() to add a string, there is no problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Well yes... [`LinkedList.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28E%29) returns a `boolean` (always `true`). You can't assign that return value into the array, because the types don't match. It's not clear what you're *trying* to do though... perhaps you wanted:

```
dictList.add(pair);
table[keyCode] = pair;
```

?

> When I declare LinkedList as String and use .add() to add a string, there is no problem.

It's not at all clear what you mean by this, but if you just change every occurrence of `DictEntry` in your code to `String`, you would get *exactly* the same problem.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to use separate chaining to solve collision issues when multiple instances of an object occupy the same index of the array. Is there a way to have the array point to the start of the linked list, which is the reason I had them in the same line..

Comment: @user1234440: Your comment is *very* unclear in multiple ways. Do you even *need* two separate collections (an array and a linked list)? Unfortunately as you've really given us no context here, we can't do much to address your fundamental problem - only the snippet you've given. (Putting a method call and an array assignment in the same statement doesn't make them atomic, by the way...)

Answer (score 1):

```
table[keyCode] = /*...*/
```

The right-hand side of this must be a `DictEntry`.

```
/*...*/ = dictList.add(pair)
```

The return value of `add()` is a boolean indicating success or failure. (For a linked list, it is always true.)